# Is "bulwarker" an acceptable word?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, verbs, nouns, agent-noun-suffix

I'm well aware that *bulwark* refers to something used as a fortification or a defense. However, I was wondering if the word *bulwarker* is an acceptable word to use in English.

I know it's possible to be a bulwark ("He built a bulwark upon the hill."), and I know you can bulwark something from something else ("I will do whatever I can to bulwark the attack."). However, I'm unsure if it is possible to be a *bulwarker*.

Comment: Well, what would a *bulwharker* be?  A person who bulwarks?

Comment: I've never encountered *bulwarker*. However, a person may (figuratively) be a *bulwark*; indeed, the most famous hymn of the Lutheran Church, "Ein Feste Burg" starts "A mighty fortress is our God, a bulwark strong and never-failing." Luther's German doesn't have anything like *bulwark* at that point, but *Burg* has much the same meaning.

Comment: According to Google, it's acceptable if you're playing Final Fantasy XIII (or it's part of your moniker on a gaming forum) or if you're on bulwarker.com, and nowhere else. Odd.

Comment: On further review, [bulwarker](http://www.websters-online-dictionary.org/definitions/bulwarkers) is also acknowledged to be one who defend[s] with a bulwark; fortif[ies] with, or as with, a rampart or wall; secure[s] by fortification; protect[s].

Comment: Rodeos are full of them.

Comment: You've left out a key component of any question like this: What do you mean by "acceptable word?" If you mean, "Can I use this word to describe someone during an informal meeting?", my answer would be "Sure, it seems fine." If you mean, "Can I use this in a paper I am submitting for an anthopology conference?" I would say, "If you have trouble finding it in a standard dictionary, I'd recommend using a different word." (Incidentally, that's the same answer I'd give to just about **any** _is-this-an-acceptable-word_ question, so you may want to include such clarifications in future questions.)

Comment: FYI, your final example "bulwark something from something else ('I will do whatever I can to bulwark the attack')" reads incorrectly to me.  I would interpret the speaker not as trying to protect someone from the attack, but as trying to strengthen the attack and make sure that it succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

There's no fundamental problem with *bulwarker* - it's just an "unlikely" word. The [only instance I can find](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=kQl8j9vBz5QC&pg=PA51&dq=%22bulwarker%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=D_XTUPDZO9HY0QWg8YCoCg&ved=0CDUQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22bulwarker%22&f=false) in Google Books is from a non-native speaker (or at least, an "Indian English" source).

Thats not surprising when you consider how rarely *bulwark* is even used as a "true" verb. Most of the [25,000 instances of "bulwarked"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20bulwarked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&gs_rn=1&gs_ri=serp&tok=ucDFJt0l1KjSqt3O_I5mvw&ds=bo&pq=%22he%20bulwarked%22&cp=1&gs_id=9&xhr=t&q=%22bulwarked%22&pf=p&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&oq=%22bulwarked%22&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.1355534169,d.d2k&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897&bs=1) are effectively "adjectival" *(the shores were well bulwarked)*. And out of over 1M instances of [bulwarks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20bulwarked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22bulwarks%22&oq=%22bulwarks%22&gs_l=serp.3...1420290.1423636.2.1424010.6.6.0.0.0.0.94.375.6.6.0...0.0...1c.1.iE9j6XzlI70&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897), only 151 are [he bulwarks](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20bulwarked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20bulwarks%22&oq=%22he%20bulwarks%22&gs_l=serp.3...24258.24943.3.25782.3.3.0.0.0.0.75.173.3.3.0...0.0...1c.1.ISuGXkgQTfw&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897).

If you want to refer to a *bulwarker*, you need to be able to say ["**he** bulwarked"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22he%20bulwarked%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#hl=en&tbo=d&tbm=bks&sclient=psy-ab&q=%22he%20bulwarked%22&oq=%22he%20bulwarked%22&gs_l=serp.3...27386.28081.1.28336.3.3.0.0.0.0.130.230.2j1.3.0...0.0...1c.1.b6PV-XqvgSE&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=631c27e467ebe0f0&bpcl=40096503&biw=1412&bih=897) (but apparently only 119 writers have). In short, you *can* use/create the word - but expect to raise a few eyebrows!